# How to solve this problem in Python Importing Stocks data?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sorry that I'm a begginer, so this might be something simple but I don't know what might be wrong.

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
tickers = ['F','MSFT','BP']
new_data = pd.DataFrame()
for t in tickers:
    new_data[t] = wb.DataReader(t, data_source='yahoo', start='2015-1-1')
```

This is the error I get:

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _ensure_valid_index(self, value)
   3524             try:
-> 3525                 value = Series(value)
   3526             except (ValueError, NotImplementedError, TypeError):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    312 
--> 313                 data = SingleBlockManager(data, index, fastpath=True)
    314 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in __init__(self, block, axis, do_integrity_check, fastpath)
   1515         if not isinstance(block, Block):
-> 1516             block = make_block(block, placement=slice(0, len(axis)), ndim=1)
   1517 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in make_block(values, placement, klass, ndim, dtype, fastpath)
   3266 
-> 3267     return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
   3268 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim)
   2774 
-> 2775         super().__init__(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
   2776 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim)
    127                 "Wrong number of items passed {val}, placement implies "
--> 128                 "{mgr}".format(val=len(self.values), mgr=len(self.mgr_locs))
    129             )

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 6, placement implies 1318

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-6f48653a5e0e> in <module>
      2 new_data = pd.DataFrame()
      3 for t in tickers:
----> 4     new_data[t] = wb.DataReader(t, data_source='yahoo', start='2015-1-1')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3470         else:
   3471             # set column
-> 3472             self._set_item(key, value)
   3473 
   3474     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3546         """
   3547 
-> 3548         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
   3549         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
   3550         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _ensure_valid_index(self, value)
   3526             except (ValueError, NotImplementedError, TypeError):
   3527                 raise ValueError(
-> 3528                     "Cannot set a frame with no defined index "
   3529                     "and a value that cannot be converted to a "
   3530                     "Series"

ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series
```

I imagine this has got something to do with missing information? Reading int as text or something? Can someone help?

This is actually from the answer key of an exercise I am doing from an online course, and it's returning this error.

Comment: does `DataReader` return a dataframe? but the issue is you can not set a value like that on the DataFrame

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! There's no need to worry if the question is simple or not. Try to avoid that kind of sentence in your questions. The only thing you need to worry about is duplicates, so please do some research before posting. Have a nice time here.

Answer (score 0):

You can only assign a column with in a dataframe with data of the same size: a column or **Series** (in Pandas terms). Let's look at what `DataReader` returns:

```
wb.DataReader('F', data_source='yahoo', start='2015-1-1').head()

Date        High    Low     Open    Close   Volume        AdjClose
2015-01-02  15.65   15.18   15.59   15.36   24777900.0  11.452041
2015-01-05  15.13   14.69   15.12   14.76   44079700.0  11.004693
2015-01-06  14.90   14.38   14.88   14.62   32981600.0  10.900313
2015-01-07  15.09   14.77   14.78   15.04   26065300.0  11.213456
2015-01-08  15.48   15.23   15.40   15.42   33943400.0  11.496773
```

It returns a **dataframe**. If you'd like to pick one column from here - say, `Open` - you can assign that to your new table.

```
tickers = ['F','MSFT','BP']
new_data = pd.DataFrame()
for t in tickers:
    new_data[t] = wb.DataReader(t, data_source='yahoo', start='2015-1-1')['Open']
new_data.head()

Date          F         MSFT       BP
2015-01-02  15.59   46.660000   38.209999
2015-01-05  15.12   46.369999   36.590000
2015-01-06  14.88   46.380001   36.009998
2015-01-07  14.78   45.980000   36.000000
2015-01-08  15.40   46.750000   36.430000
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign to a dictionary;

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
tickers = ['F','MSFT','BP']
new_data = {}
for t in tickers:
    new_data[t] = wb.DataReader(t, data_source='yahoo', start='2015-1-1')

print(new_data['F'])
```

you are trying to assign a dataframe to each column of a dataframe